# What is the correct operator < or &&

Tags: javascript

I need to sort a objects within an array based on a boolean property. My code works but it doesn't seem to be the proper way and I can't figure out why.

```js
const todos = [{
  text: 'Check emails for the day',
  completed: true
},{
  text: 'Walk the dog',
  completed: true
},{
  text: 'Go to the store for groceries',
  completed: false
},{
  text: 'Pick up kids from school',
  completed: false
},{
  text: 'Do online classes',
  completed: false
}]

const sortTodos = function (todos) {
  todos.sort(function (a,b) {
    if (a.completed < b.completed) { // (or) a.completed === false && b.completed === true
      return -1
    } else if (b.completed < a.completed){ // (or) !b.completed && a.completed
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
}

sortTodos(todos)
console.log(todos)
```

Should I be using the greater than less than operator or the including operator "&&"?

```
(b.completed < a.completed){ // (or) !b.completed && a.completed
```

Comment: Well you could just use `return a.completed - b.completed;` if you're comfortable with coercing the boolean values to numbers, as your code already does.

Comment: Personally, I would keep the `<`, because I'm used to how sorting is performed in js. Or as Pointy suggested, and the answer already given, using the difference. I think your concern is readability, which is a good concern to have in my opinion. But the comparison with "greater than" and the fact that `false < true` because `0 < 1` is quite idiomatic in js (and other languages).  It seems less surprising than having to perform multiple boolean operations with `(not A) AND B`. At the end of the day, ask yourself (or your colleagues) which versions you better understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the delta of the boolean values. The subtraction coerces the values to numbers.

```js
const
    todos = [{ text: 'Check emails for the day', completed: true }, { text: 'Walk the dog', completed: true }, { text: 'Go to the store for groceries', completed: false }, { text: 'Pick up kids from school', completed: false }, { text: 'Do online classes', completed: false }],
    sortTodos = todos => todos.sort((a, b) => a.completed - b.completed);

sortTodos(todos);
console.log(todos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```